# Is it faster to use stream() and sorted(), or the Collections method to reverse list order

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to find out which one is faster:

```
Collections.reverse(bottlesList);




bottlesList= bottlesList.stream().sorted(Collections.reverseOrder()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: How big is the list? With or without a `parallel` stream? If yes, how many cores? Only a microbenchmark with a framework like JMH can tell.

Comment: Why not implicitly reverse the list, that would be in `O(1)`, if applicable. You cant do it faster than implicit. Create a wrapper implementation which forwards all method calls with reversed order. Depending on the underlying list implementation, you could easily traverse a list backwards (works for `ArrayList`, as well as for `LinkedList`).

Comment: Voting to close as it needs details (see first comment).

Comment: `Collections.reverse` just reverses the order of elements (n/2 swaps)

Comment: My _educated guess_: If it is not benefitial to use multithreading (because the list is maybe small), then `Collections.reverse` likely yields the best possible performance.

Comment: Consider that in a standard use case with a small list, the `Stream` approach creates a new list and does a lot more work than `Collections.reverse()`. Not to mention the the difference in amount of typing. Is it really a performance hotspot for you to reverse collections? If so, consider Zabuzard's second comment. If it's not a hotspot, then you're asking the wrong question. They have different use cases, but performance is not the primary motivation to choose between them.

Comment: Both operations not doing same thing then what is the point which one is faster ?

Comment: @Eklavya exactly, out of given options there is only one right choice here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Collections.reverse` is only option here that will reverse elements based on index, regarding time complexity it is linear operation.

`sorted(Collections.reverseOrder())` will sort based on Comparator so it will sort by value not index.

Simple comparison:

```
    List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(4,3,5,7,1);
    List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(4,3,5,7,1);

    Collections.reverse(list1);
    System.out.println(list1);
    // Output: [1, 7, 5, 3, 4]

    List<Integer> list3 = list2.stream().sorted(Collections.reverseOrder()).collect(Collectors.toList());;
    System.out.println(list3);
    // Output: [7, 5, 4, 3, 1]
```